# R ave with multiple arguments / rank by group with weighting

Tags: r, rank

I am using ave for ranking values within groups in a dataset in R. In the example 'data' is a data.frame with the cols raw, group and others, for example

```
data <- data.frame(raw = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), weight = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
```

The ranking works fine with

```
data$rank <- ave(data$raw, data$group, FUN = function(x) {rank(x)})
```

I would like to generalize this approach by applying weights. The weights are available as another col in the data.frame. The weighted ranking is a self defined function that needs both the raw scores and the weights vector. It is available via the cNORM package, code: https://github.com/WLenhard/cNORM/blob/master/R/utilities.R
Is it possible to use ave with multiple input variables, e. g.

```
data$rank <- ave(x = data$raw, data$group, y = data$weights, FUN = function(x, y) {weighted.rank(x, weights = y)})
```

so that both x and y are both the according subsets based on the grouping variable? I guess packages like dplyr have functions for that. Is there a way to do that with base R as well and without changing the order of the rows in the original data frame?

Many thanks!

Edit: The solution from Ronak Shah perfectly solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Have you already written `weighted.rank` function? Can you provide dataset in a reproducible format along with expected output so that it is easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, the weighted.rank function is ready and available via https://github.com/WLenhard/cNORM/blob/master/R/utilities.R . An example for the dataset:
data <- data.frame(raw = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), weight = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
(Code added to the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `by` for base R option.

```
library(cNORM)

data$rank <- unlist(by(data, data$group, function(x) weighted.rank(x$raw, x$weight)))
```

In `dplyr` you could do :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(rank  = weighted.rank(raw, weight))
```